# How to make two images with same dimensions to be same size in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-resizing

I have two images with same dimensions but with different sizes. I want the bigger image's size to be changed to match the smaller image's size. 
For example, I have an image A with size `300x400x3` and image B with size `600x800x3`. I want to change the size of image B to `300x400x3`. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just one-liner as suggested by Andrey -

```
B = imresize( B,[size(A,1) size(A,2)]);
```

For accessing more options with resizing, use this [resource](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/imresize.html).

Comment: You can use `imresize` on `A`, no need to do it on each channel separately.

Comment: @Andrey, thanks! Didn't know that, edited accordingly :)

Comment: @Divakar Could you explain the second argument of the imresize? I don't get it.

Comment: @SavK The second argument is a vector of the desired sizes.